# Trying to get List of Groups for a user using SPServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices

I came across this code and I'm trying to use it in SP 2010 Foundation. When I load the page, I get the error saying "User not found". I'm using Jquery 1.10.X and the latest SPServices version. I assume it has something to do with the "userLoginName" but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Populate the users pick list
  var strHTMLSiteUsers = "";
  $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
          strHTMLSiteUsers += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("LoginName") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
        });
        $("#my_SiteUsers").append(strHTMLSiteUsers);
      }
  });
  RefreshGroupLists();
});

function RefreshGroupLists(){
  var strHTMLAvailable = "";
  var strHTMLAssigned = "";
  var arrOptionsAssigned = new Array();
  var intOpts = 0;
  var booMatch;
  var booErr = "false";

  $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").html("");
  $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").html("");

  if($("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value") == 0){
    alert("You must select a user");
    return;
  }

  //Populate the Groups Assigned
  $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: $("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value"),
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("errorstring").each(function() {
          alert("User not found");
          booErr = "true";
          return;
        });
        $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function() {
          strHTMLAvailable += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("Name") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
          arrOptionsAssigned[intOpts] = $(this).attr("Name");
          intOpts = intOpts + 1;
        });
        $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").append(strHTMLAvailable);
      }
  });

  //Populate available site groups
  if(booErr == "false"){
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromSite",
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function() {
            booMatch = "false";
            for (var i=0;i<=arrOptionsAssigned.length;i++){
              if($(this).attr("Name") == arrOptionsAssigned[i]){
                booMatch = "true";
                break;
              }
            }
            if(booMatch == "false"){
              strHTMLAssigned += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("Name") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
            }
          });
          $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").append(strHTMLAssigned);
        }
    });
  }
}

function AddGroupsToUser(){
  var i;

  if($("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value") == 0){
    alert("You must select a user");
    return;
  }

  if($("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").val() == null){
    alert("You haven't selected any groups to add");
    return;
  }
  else{
    var arrGroups = $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").val();
    for (i=0;i<arrGroups.length;i++){
      $().SPServices({
          operation: "AddUserToGroup",
          groupName: arrGroups[i],
          userLoginName: $("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value"),
          async: false,
          completefunc: null
      });
    }
    RefreshGroupLists();
  }
}

function RemoveGroupsFromUser(){
  var i

  if($("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value") == 0){
    alert("You must select a user");
    return;
  }

  if($("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").val() == null){
    alert("You haven't selected any groups to remove");
    return;
  }
  else{
    var arrGroups = $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").val();
    for (i=0;i<arrGroups.length;i++){
      $().SPServices({
          operation: "RemoveUserFromGroup",
          groupName: arrGroups[i],
          userLoginName: $("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value"),
          async: false,
          completefunc: null
      });
    }
    RefreshGroupLists();
  }
}
```

This is the [source](http://sympmarc.com/2011/11/03/managing-sharepoint-site-user-memberships-in-multiple-groups-using-spservices/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Firebug (addon of Firefox) to look at the AJAX requests that are done. Like that you can see the exact error message.

I know that usually you have to pass an username with "-1;#" in front of it to make Sharepoint to recognize it as an username (for example: "-1;#john_doe@test.com")... maybe it's the reason?!

Instead of SPServices you could use [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) and its [groupMembers](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.groupMembers) function:

```
$SP().groupMembers("my group", function(members) {
  for (var i=0; i < members.length; i++) console.log(members[i]);
  // -> {ID:"1234", Name:"Doe, John", LoginName:"mydomain\john_doe", Email:"john_doe@rainbow.com"}
});
```

Comment: Just quickly looking at the methods available in SharePointPlus, wouldn't using "usergroups" method be a closer equivalent to GetGroupCollectionFromUser

Comment: I successfully managed to get $SP().usergroups to give me a list of the users a selected user belongs to. Now, I just need to figure out how to merge that with the above code to get it to work. Right now it's just writing a console log :(

Comment: Instead of using console, you can create some HTML code and insert it in your page... I don't understand what is difficult here ?!

Answer (score 0):

This solution was written using an earlier version of jQuery; the identification of an element's "properties" (vs its "attributes") changed at some point.  I had your exact problem and this was the issue:

If you're using jQuery 1.10.X+ you'll need to replace every occurrence of `.attr("value")` with `.prop("value")` in your source code for this to work.